# Maximum Likelihood estimator for GARCH with jump (papers on this topic)

Tags: references, econometrics, garch

Does anyone know a reference to a paper that would show an actual calibration of GARCH(1,1) model with jumps to a historical time series?

Answer (score 0):

This paper: [*Gerlach, Naimoli  and Storti - Time Varying Heteroskedastic Realized GARCH models for tracking
measurement error bias in volatility forecasting*](https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/83893/1/MPRA_paper_83893.pdf) utilizing the Realized GARCH framework may be interesting